# Rearrange divs in certain way when resizing

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I have created flexbox to rearrange the boxes. Here is the [demo code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-umxan5?file=index.html,index.js,style.css)

The problem is that when I resize for smaller screen, I want to insert `B` between `A` and `C`.

[image]

How can I achieve that ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can `a` `b` and `c` be placed in the same parent container?

Comment: you can use [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items)

Comment: You have sufficient reputation to know in advance that your relevant "*[mcve]*" code should be in your question; may I ask why you chose not to bother?

Comment: @DavidThomas I wrote the styling which I could to show my effort. Check my demo code. The answer was simple, it is just that I did not know about `grid` . Hence, I provided diagram for the result that I was expecting.

Comment: Your demo code should be in your question, please read the link I provided to guidance. Those trying to help shouldn't be expected to visit external sites in order to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

grid is the grid-system you may need for this kind of layout.

here is a short example

```css
/* let make a grid of 2 columns */
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  margin: 20px;
}
/* b should span through 2 rows */
.b {
  grid-row: span 2;
}
/* clear the grid system on small screen */
@media (max-width: 639px) {
  .main {
    display: block;
  }
}


/* original styling for bg */
.a {
  background-color: red;
}

.b {
  background-color: green;
}

.c {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="a">A - I have some content</div>
  <div class="b">B - I have some content</div>
  <div class="c">C - I have some content</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, you may need little HTML and CSS to get this organized. Mind to set your media query in last position so it is not overridden ;)

see https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ to dig further into grid

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution that gather all classes a b and c in one container:

html code :

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="container-1">
    <div class="a">A - I have some content</div>
    <div class="b">B - I have some content</div>
    <div class="c">C - I have some content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS code :

```
.a {
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
}

.b {
  background-color: green;
  height: 30px;
}

.c {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 20px;
}

.container-1 div{
  width: 45%;
  display: inline-block;
}

@media (max-width: 639px) {
  .container-1 div {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier using grid instead flex:

***HTML***

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="a">a</div>
    <div class="b">b</div>
    <div class="c">c</div>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
.main {
    display: grid; /* If you don't wanna add a gap between blocks, put this attribute into the media query */
    gap: 1rem; /* To add a gap between blocks */
}

.a {
    background: red;
}

.b {
    background: green;
}

.c {
    background: blue;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .main {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; 
        grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr; 
    }

    .a {
        grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
    }

    .b {
        grid-area: 1 / 2 / 3 / 3;
    }

    .c {
        grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
    }
}
```